# Как реализовать такой TabLayout (имеется в виду с таким дизайном)?

Tags: android, design, android-drawable

Хочу реалиовать у себя в приложении такой переход между табами, но не могу найти ни библиотеки, ни стандартных функций для такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует вариант размытия снизу и такого размещения слайдов

Comment: это же обычный бэк с градиентом из вдух цветов красный-белый, разве нет?

Comment: @Pentiux да, это просто статичное, заранее подготовленное изображение в бэкграунде виджета